# Remove checkbox items from anywhere in an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Suppose I have a parent checkbox and under this I have four child checkboxes. For example-

-Animals
-Cat
-Dog
-Squirrel
-Lion

If I select the parent, then all the childs will be selected. If I deselect all the child, the parent will be unselected. If I select only one child then also the parent will be selected. How to implement this in vue.js ?

**json:**

```
{
  "id": 266,
  "parent_id": 0,
  "menu_name": "Server && DB Info",
  "menu_url": "#",
  "menu_icon": "fa fa-database",
  "order_by": 6,
  "has_child": 1,
  "child": [
    {
      "id": 269,
      "parent_id": 266,
      "menu_name": "Client",
      "menu_url": "/server_and_db_info/client",
      "menu_icon": null,
      "order_by": 7,
      "has_child": 0,
      "child": []
    },
    {
      "id": 268,
      "parent_id": 266,
      "menu_name": "VPN",
      "menu_url": "/server_and_db_info/vpn",
      "menu_icon": null,
      "order_by": 8,
      "has_child": 0,
      "child": []
    },
    {
      "id": 262,
      "parent_id": 266,
      "menu_name": "Server",
      "menu_url": "/server_and_db_info/server",
      "menu_icon": "",
      "order_by": 9,
      "has_child": 0,
      "child": []
    },
    {
      "id": 267,
      "parent_id": 266,
      "menu_name": "Database",
      "menu_url": "/server_and_db_info/database",
      "menu_icon": null,
      "order_by": 10,
      "has_child": 0,
      "child": []
    },
    {
      "id": 271,
      "parent_id": 266,
      "menu_name": "Domain",
      "menu_url": "/server_and_db_info/domain",
      "menu_icon": null,
      "order_by": 15,
      "has_child": 0,
      "child": []
    }
  ]
}
```

**Code:**

```
<div
  class="menu-padding padding-top"
  v-for="(data, index) in getAllMenu"
  :key="index"
>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    v-model="selectedMenu"
    :value="data.id"
    @change="select(data.id, index)"
  />
  <label>{{ data.menu_name }}</label>
  <div
    class="padding-left"
    v-if="data.child.length > 0"
  >
    <div
      v-for="(data_child, index) in data.child"
      :key="index"
    >
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        v-model="selectedMenu"
        :value="data_child.id"
        @change="selectChild(data.id, data_child.id)"
      />
      <label>{{ data_child.menu_name }} {{ data_child.id }}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add the sample code which you used to show check boxes, also add the JSON you used

Comment: Provided the code and JSON.

Comment: Can someone answer ? Please I need help

Answer (score 1):

Try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      getAllMenu: [
        {"id": 256, "menu_name": "Server", "child": []},
        {"id": 266, "menu_name": "Server && DB Info", "child": [
          {"id": 269, "menu_name": "Client",},
          {"id": 268, "menu_name": "VPN",},
          {"id": 262, "menu_name": "Server",},
          {"id": 267, "menu_name": "Database",},
          {"id": 271, "menu_name": "Domain",}
        ]},
        {"id": 286, "menu_name": "Info", "child": [
          {"id": 289, "menu_name": "C",},
          {"id": 288, "menu_name": "V",},
          {"id": 282, "menu_name": "S",},
          {"id": 287, "menu_name": "D",},
        ]},
      ],
      selectedMenu: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selChild(id) {
      return this.selectedMenu.find(s => s.child.find(c => c.id === id))
    },
    selParent(id) {
      return this.selectedMenu.find(s => s.id === id)
    },
    select(data) {
      if(this.selectedMenu.find(s => s.id === data.id)) {
        this.selectedMenu = this.selectedMenu.filter(s => s.id !== data.id)
      } else {
        this.selectedMenu.push(data)
      }
    },
    selectChild(id, childId) {
      if (this.selectedMenu.length) {
        let par = this.selectedMenu.find(s => s.id === id)
        let parent = {...par}
        let idx = this.getAllMenu.findIndex(f => f.id === id)
        if (par && parent.child.find(p => p.id === childId)) {
          if(parent.child.length > 1) {
            parent.child = parent.child.filter(c => c.id !== childId)
            let i = this.selectedMenu.findIndex(f => f.id === parent.id)
            this.selectedMenu = this.selectedMenu.filter(m => m.id !== parent.id)
            this.selectedMenu.push(parent)
          } else {
            this.selectedMenu = this.selectedMenu.filter(s => s.id !== id)
          }
        } else {
          let ch = [...this.getAllMenu]
          if(par) {
            ch = ch[idx].child.filter(f => f.id === childId)
            parent.child.push(...ch)
          } else {
            par = this.getAllMenu.find(f => f.id === id)
            let parent = {...par}
            parent.child = parent.child.filter(f => f.id === childId)
            this.selectedMenu.push(parent)
          }
        }
      } else {
        let par = this.getAllMenu.find(s => s.id === id)
        let parent = {...par}
        parent.child = parent.child.filter(c => c.id === childId)
        this.selectedMenu.push(parent)
      }
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```css
.padding-left {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <ul>
    <li
      class="menu-padding padding-top"
      v-for="(data, index) in getAllMenu"
      :key="data.id"
    >
      <input type="checkbox" :value="data.id" @change="select(data)" :checked="selParent(data.id)" />
      <label>{{ data.menu_name }}</label>
      <ul class="padding-left" >
        <li v-for="data_child in data.child" :key="data_child.id">
          <input type="checkbox" :value="data_child.id" @change="selectChild(data.id, data_child.id)" :checked="selChild(data_child.id)" />
          <label>{{ data_child.menu_name }} - {{ data_child.id }}</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>{{ selectedMenu }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: console error:  cannot read properties of undefined (reading find)

Comment: Hey mate, did you copy all code, like you can see in snippet there are no errors?

Comment: There are several functions inside my methods. When I am pasting codes, its showing errors as there are other functions. Could you please update your functions, so that it does not conflict with other functions in my code? Otherwise the html part is ok.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you provided the same `v-model` to all of your checkboxes without reference for each of it. That means, that `v-model="selectedMenu"` get´s overwritten by every new value that is passed by any element that uses this `v-model`.

As your data is nested, you should pre-build the `v-model` for this. Define a object like this:

```
myVModel: {}
```

This function will check, if your provided data, in this case named `myObject`, has childs, if yes, it will expand your `v-model` `myModel` for each child:

```
preBuildVModel() {
      Object.keys(this.myObject).forEach(parentId => {
        if(this.myObject[parentId].has_child === 1) {
          Object.assign(this.myVModel, {[this.myObject[parentId].id]: {
              'parent': null,
              'childs': {}
            }
          })
          Object.keys(this.myObject[parentId].child).forEach(childId => {
            console.log(this.myObject[parentId].child[childId].id)
            Object.assign(this.myVModel[this.myObject[parentId].id].childs,
                {[this.myObject[parentId].child[childId].id]: null
            })
          });
        }
        else {
          Object.assign(this.myVModel, {[this.myObject[parentId].id]: {
              'parent': null
            }
          })
        }
      });
    }
```

I added another parent to your provided data, as I asume there are multiple parents and also the case, that there are no parents. In my example there is another parent with `id` 100 and no children. The `myVModel` would look like this:

```
{
   "100":{
      "parent":null
   },
   "266":{
      "parent":null,
      "childs":{
         "262":null,
         "267":null,
         "268":null,
         "269":null,
         "271":null
      }
   }
}
```

So you need to fix your hook now, as your `v-model` needs to be set correctly. I will set them to my examples, just change them to the declared names you used:

```
<div class="menu-padding padding-top" v-for="(data, index) in myObject" :key="index">
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            v-model="myVModel[data.id].parent"
            :value="data.id"
        />
        <label>{{ data.menu_name }}</label>
        <div class="padding-left" v-if="data.child.length > 0">
          <div v-for="(data_child, index) in data.child" :key="index">
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                v-model="myVModel[data.id].childs[data_child.id]"
                :value="data_child.id"
            />
            <label>{{ data_child.menu_name }} {{ data_child.id }}</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I deleted your `@change` as you not provided them.

Comment: error myObject is not defined.

Comment: @alprazolam Did you read the instructions? I wrote that I named your data `json` as `myObject`.

Comment: facing problems changing v-model

Comment: @alprazolam Can you please be more specific? Your comment doesn´t provide any information.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this from another source and it's working:

```
  <div
    class="menu-padding padding-top"
    v-for="(data, index) in getAllMenu"
    :key="index"
  >
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      v-model="selectedMenu"
      :value="data.id"
      @change="select(data.id, index)"
    />
    <label>{{ data.menu_name }}</label>
    <div
      class="padding-left"
      v-if="data.child.length > 0"
    >
      <div
        v-for="(data_child, index_child) in data.child"
        :key="index_child"
      >
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          v-model="selectedMenu"
          :value="data_child.id"
          @change="
            selectChild(data.id, data_child.id, index)
          "
        />
        <label>{{ data_child.menu_name }}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the **functions:**

```
selectChild(id, child_id, index) {
      this.$nextTick(function () {
        const self = this;
        if (this.selectedMenu.includes(child_id)) {
          this.selectedMenu.push(id);

          this.selectedMenu = [...new Set(this.selectedMenu)];
          //  console.log(this.selectedMenu);
        } else {
          var arrData = false;
          this.getAllMenu[index].child.forEach((data) => {
            console.log(data.id);

            if (self.selectedMenu.includes(data.id)) {
              arrData = true;
            }
          });

          if (arrData === false) {
            console.log(this.getAllMenu[index].id);
            this.selectedMenu = this.arrayRemove(
              this.selectedMenu,
              this.getAllMenu[index].id
            );
          }

          // this.selectedMenu.pop(id)
          this.selectedMenu = [...new Set(this.selectedMenu)];
        }
      });
    },
    select(id, index) {
      this.$nextTick(function () {
        if (this.selectedMenu.includes(id)) {
          if (this.getAllMenu[index].child.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.getAllMenu[index].child.length; i++) {
              this.selectedMenu.push(this.getAllMenu[index].child[i].id);
            }
            console.log(this.selectedMenu);
          }
        } else {
          for (let i = 0; i < this.getAllMenu[index].child.length; i++) {
            this.selectedMenu = this.arrayRemove(
              this.selectedMenu,
              this.getAllMenu[index].child[i].id
            );
          }
          console.log(this.selectedMenu);
        }
      });

      //console.log(this.selectedMenu)
    },

    arrayRemove: function (arr, value) {
      return arr.filter(function (ele) {
        return ele != value;
      });
    },
```